# Conditionals: と良いだ/です should be wrong?

Tags: politeness, conditionals, i-adjectives

It is said that the と conditional must not be used where the main clause expresses any of the following: an intention, a suggestion, a command, an obligation, a request, etc. However, I've encountered `と良いです` a lot. E.g. `すぐに薬を飲むと良いですよ。` Should this be considered grammatically wrong, but in fact readily acceptable in reality?

*Trivial: I'm trying to tackle this beast called conditionals in Japanese, and the fact that various sources I've read online seem to have contradictory explanations/definitions isn't helping. I've looked all over the Net.

Comment: `I've encountered と良いだ/です a lot` <-- 「良いです」はいいですけど、「良いだ」とは言いません。。。eg ◎「おいしいです」✖「おいしいだ」

Comment: Yet another beginner blunder. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: I did not wish to flood the forum with my questions, but I understand how it's considered poor practice. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no problem as it is. While the whole sentence implies recommendation, the main clause 良い itself is not any of modal expressions you listed but a statement, literally, "if you take medicine immediately, that's good".

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, do you mean that while it sounds like a suggestion in nature, grammar-wise it simply isn't?

Comment: When you see 良い alone, do you still find it a suggestion?